# MySQL update fields of a record based on field designation from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a "Master" table that I am trying to apply a table of changes to.  The "Master" is a table is from a point in time from the past.  Changes that have been made to the "Master" since that time are listed in "Changes", and I am given the record number, the name of the field that needs to be updated, the new value of the field, and the date/time it was changed.  If I cannot take the latest change, that is not an issue, as I can just change the table so that it only has the latest update.  My issue is getting a query to update a field in a record, where I am getting the field name to update from a different table.

Any ideas?  I started my code off hard coding equations but wonder if there is a dynamic way to do this.

```
UPDATE MASTER
INNER JOIN MASTER b
   ON a.Id = b.Id
SET b.description = a.New_Value
WHERE a.change_field = "Description"

......(then I need it to do the same for any instance of one of the other 3 fields)

;
```

Table "MASTER":

```
    Id        | Description | Brand   | Cost   | Mapping
    --------------------------------------------------
    123       |  A Desc     |   Any   |  0.01  | Candy
    456       |  B Desc     |   Old   |  0.02  | Baking
    789       |  C Desc     |   Brand |  0.03  | Season
```

Table "CHANGES":

```
    Id           | Change Field   |   New Value  | Change Time
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    123          | Description    |   AA Desc    |  01:15:00
    123          | Description    |   AAA Desc   |  12:15:00
    456          | Brand          |   Good       |  01:15:00
    456          | Brand          |   Best       |  12:15:00
    789          | Cost           |   0.44       |  01:15:00
    789          | Mapping        |   Salt       |  01:15:00
    789          | Mapping        |   Sugar      |  12:15:00
```

Table "MASTER", updated with "CHANGES":

```
    Item Code | Description | Brand   | Cost   | Mapping
    --------------------------------------------------
    123       |  AAA Desc   |   Any   |  0.01  | Candy
    456       |  B Desc     |   Best  |  0.02  | Baking
    789       |  C Desc     |   Brand |  0.44  | Sugar
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not at all sure you can do this. In SQL-Server there is a way but it would be a horrible design if I actually did it. Find a better design!

Comment: @simon at rcl - it is actually damage control / correction :)  We have the change records, we just need to get them updated to the main table.

Comment: Actually, you've got the way I was going to it up there. However, you need one statement for each field: first for description, then for Brand, a third for Cost and a fourth for Mapping. Not efficient, but if it's a one-off activity probably not worth spending much more time on.

Comment: @simon at rcl - thank you so much for confirming my guess that there is no easy query to run on this.  you saved me time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do if there is no enough time, 
Copy/export all rows from `CHANGES` table to excel sheet. 
Then build query there on excel using `CONCATENATE` formula, Check snap below.

[image]

Once your formula is perfect, just drag it up-to all rows below.

Then just copy paste the whole bunch from the Excel column to your query browser and execute it.

One more thing : if you want to update with latest value by time (in your case there are 2 rows for the `description`,`branch` and `mapping` fields with different `Change Time`) then you need to copy only those records which needs to be processed. e.g. While selecting the records from the `Changes` table you need to use `group by Change Time` and `Max`

You also need to handle other data type then string with slight change when you generate formula - i mentioned on the snap.

Let me know if it does not help or you need more help.

Mark it as answer if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this this is a straight forward approach. Because I will be updating record by record, it will give me the confidence that ALL updates have been performed.  I am not well versed in mySql (yet) and it would have felt like I was throwing code into the wind, hoping that everything was updated.